# Updating AWS Credentials from a running CLI Go program in order to access a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I am new to AWS and have not found an answer in my research online. I am creating a CLI tool in Go that will pull down all the contents from an s3 bucket locally, then allow you to input new credentials, and then push those contents to a bucket in the new environment.

I am running into an issue where I am to input the new credentials. Here is the code:

```
type MyProvider struct{
    creds        credentials.Value
}

func getNewCredentials() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Copy new AWS Access Key: ")
    AK, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Copy new AWS Secret Access Key: ")
    SAK, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Copy new AWS session token: ")
    ST, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("New stage name(poc, dev, qa, prod): ")
    lib.Stage, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')

    provider := MyProvider{
        creds: credentials.Value{AK, SAK, ST, ""},
    }

    creds := credentials.NewCredentials(&provider)

}
```

I am using a custom provider, and I have overwritten the provider functions Retrieve() and isExpired() (not shown in code snippet).

When I try and access the new bucket, it says the bucket does not exist, leading me to believe the credentials did not properly update. My guess is this has to do with the blank providername at the end of the Value struct. I am not sure what to put there.

Any guidance on how to fix this would be very helpful. The program is not throwing any errors, but rather just not actually updating the credentials.

Comment: Check if you have the permissions to change the credentials for a bucket and you can access bucket before changing the credentials and access grants on the bucket.

Comment: use `GetCallerIdentity` under the sts service to verify your credentials' accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials suggests that you instantiate like this :

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("AKID", "SECRET_KEY", "TOKEN"),
})
```

If I were trying to do this, I would have the accounts share a trust relationship by allowing one to assume a role in the other, rather than passing credentials.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

It's wonderfully convenient in go:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/stscreds/

Comment: Perfect thank you! And yes I was thinking about doing it with with cross account roles like that but I was advised against it for security reasons. Having to go get new credentials in the middle of running the program isn't ideal but it should work for the time being. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: you could accept it , if you think it's a right answer, to help others find it too